# ExtJS Grid selection getSelectionModel() doesn't seems to work

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am encountering a strange behaviour regarding my grid selection:

I have a simple grid, but when I select a record, I do:

```
var grid = this.getExternrulesgrid();  
var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var rec = this.getSelectedExternRule();
```

But for some reason, `records` is empty?!

Do you have any idea as to why?

Thank you!!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: First check whether you are getting your grid object properly.And here  with "select an item",you mean to say selecting the record ?

Comment: Yes Damon, my grid variable/object is fine and yes, you are right, I meant selecting a record in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

> Their are various ways you can get the selected record.

1.You can use **selectionchange** event listener.

```
selectionchange( this, selected, eOpts ){
}
```

Here, selected : The selected records.

2.Using selection model on some action

```
selected=[];
selctn = grid.getSelectionModel();
var s = selctn.getSelection();
Ext.each(s, function(item) {
    selected.push(item);
});
```

You will be getting the array of selected records in **selected** array.

> Note: Check your grid object.

Comment: Thing is it doesn't work using selection model, getSelection() returns an empty array in my case (see my last picture).

Comment: I am not bit clear about your approach.Here it is, a simple fiddle to demonstrate : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6be .Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it's pretty clear. What I don't understand is that I am doing the same thing (grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()) but got an empty array instead.